# Make glyphicon act as a button (style-wise)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I wish to have a glyphicon that acts as a button when clicked, to have that inset effect.
When you press it to make it look as if its getting "pushed back" like a button

All I have so far is `.button-glyph:active { }` but I don't know what properties I can use to achieve the effect

Comment: So `<a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></a>` is not an option?

Comment: @Shron can you provide code here. ?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: @Aadeshara there is no further code to provide, I see no point in providing the html that for this purpose contains a span with glyphicon class

Comment: @Paulie_D refer to the the comment above. Please try and understand the situation next time, as I mentioned all I got to was the active pseudo at the css. No thought direction as to how to achieve this. Reached a dead-end so came here to ask. Googled "make glyphicon act as a button" and such, all I got was functionality solutions and not UI as I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css,

```
.btn:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.95);
            transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

Comment: Ended up using this solution. Closest to my goal. Thanks! I'll be happy if there would be the inset effect but its great like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to apply an box-shadow with type inset, here is an example: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/#article-header-id-1

```
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
```

Comment: Box shadow won't be good because it will create a shadow over the span, which will create the rectangle shape and not the glyphicon shape